# ASP.NET MVC routing across server

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to route WCF data services request from one server to another server.
Is it possible to route a request across servers using ASP.NET MVC routing module?
What are the options available for routing WCF data services request across servers?

Comment: What do you mean by routing in this case? Is it just forwarding or do you need to work with / inspect request itself before you now the target of routing?

Comment: I Need to foward the request. There is no need to look into the contents of the request. I coudn't get any example from asp.net routing moudle which routes the request across the servers. All the examples are routing the request within the same web application. Is it posssible to route the request across servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not scenario for ASP.NET routing module. Routing module only routes request to handler within same web application. That is not real request router.

What you are looking for is usually performed on network level and it is called [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Example of more powerful reverse proxy from MS world is ISA server.

If you don't have such server available (then the question is why do you need this?) using routing module will only allow you to route request to some handler within current application. You will have to implement that handler so that it takes incoming request and uses `WebClient` to call the real service and return a response.

Edit:

Check also [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server). It describes some modules for IIS allowing functionality of reverse proxy.

Comment: We looked at the various options and decided to go with Application Request Routing for the scenarion I have mentiond. That solves our problem.